# Firebug doesn't show JSON tab in console

Tags: javascript, razor, getjson, webmatrix

I am debugging my javascript code (below).

The webgrid is populated after a user has clicked the search button. I have added a button to the webgrid which opens a dialog that has to be populated with values from a JSON object.

This is where the problem is - when I debug using firebug the JSON tab in the console is not shown.

Below is the part of my code:

```
 $('.edit-recipients').live('click', function ()
           {
               $.getJSON('/Methods/GetRecipients/' + $(this).attr('id'), function (data)
               {
                   var recipient = data;
                   console.log(recipient);
               $('#edit-opno').val(recipient.OpNo);
```

Console.log(recipient) shows the values from my `GetRecipients` method.
This code  `$('#edit-opno').val(recipient.OpNo);` is meant to show the value in my input text where I have this code below.

```
<input type="text" name="opno" id="edit-opno" size="15" />
```

However at first I thought the GetRecipients was not executed but from firebug realized it is executed with console.log(recipients) showing the values but no JSON tab, hence failing to populate my dialog input box.

Below is my server side code:

```
@{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    if(UrlData[0].IsInt()){
        var db = Database.Open("sb_cpd");
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM cpd_recipients WHERE ID = @0";
        var recipients = db.QuerySingle(sql,UrlData[0]);
        Json.Write(recipients, Response.Output);
    }
}
```

I have inserted an image of whats happening. Notice my dialog is not populated with values from GetRecipients method.
[image]

Comment: Sounds like the response header _content-type_ is not set to _application/json_

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have set my $.ajax({ type : "POST", contentType : "application/json", etc; but still no binding of data to input text and no JSON tab.

Comment: That will set the request header, not the response header. The response header has to be set serverside. Could you show some serverside code?

Comment: show us your GetRecipients method

Comment: @CristiPufu  I have edited the question and included the GetRecipients method.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the header content-type to application/json. Firebug will then recognize the response as JSON:

```
@{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    if(UrlData[0].IsInt()){
        var db = Database.Open("sb_cpd");
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM cpd_recipients WHERE ID = @0";
        var recipients = db.QuerySingle(sql,UrlData[0]);
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
        Json.Write(recipients, Response.Output);
    }
}
```